# JOptionPane.showMessageDialog invalid AnnotationName

Tags: java

Following some java courses beginner level, got into this issue:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token "showMessageDialog", invalid 
     AnnotationName
    - Syntax error on token "(", { expected after this token
    - Syntax error on tokens, ConstructorHeaderName expected instead
```

and the line is:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The answer is " +sum, "The Title", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Java Docs says this method accepts 4 params, so I am sending 4 params. Also I have imported required library:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
```

`JOptionPane.showInputDialog` works ok, but not `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`. What am I missing?
Thank you.

---

**Full Code**

```
package java_practice;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class GraphicalUserInterface {
    String first_number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter first number");
    String second_number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter second number");

    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(first_number);
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(second_number);
    int sum = num1 + num2;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The answer is " +sum, "The Title", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: What's the line before the one reporting the error...?

Comment: @Adam I'll put the code.. 1 moment.

Comment: is that your code .do this inside a method

Comment: @FastSnail thank you.. noob error, have to pay more attention next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've missed the method declaration. Your code is inside the body of the class which is confusing the compiler/IDE, e.g. the errors about invalid annotations etc.

Needs to be inside a method of some form, block or static block.

```
public class GraphicalUserInterface {
    public static void main(String [] args) {  //  <=========

        String first_number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter first number");
        String second_number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter second number");

        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(first_number);
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(second_number);
        int sum = num1 + num2;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The answer is " +sum, "The Title", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

   } //  <=========
}
```

Comment: Missed the main block.. OMG ... noob.. thank you. +1 and I'll accept it in 5 minutes. ;)

Comment: No worries, we've all been there :)